# How to homogenize points using lidR to reduce streaking artifacts

Tags: r, point-clouds, lidar, lidr

I am trying to homogenize an aerial LAS catalog to achieve a consistent point density across a large study area. The dataset ranges from less than 4 points per meter to greater than 8 points per meter, with many areas of extreme point density in overlapping swathes. Certain raster metrics I calculate generate streaking artifacts with lines of low value pixels occurring where high point density meets lower point density (see screenshot of output 10m IQR). I hope to fix this by thinning points to a more even consistency by using the homogenize option in `lidR::decimate_points()`. While running this function, a came across another issue where `summary()` reports a successful decimation, but the output files appear the same as the input files.

I tried numerous density and resolution combinations to ensure I wasn't making simple USft to meter conversion errors. The R book mentions that attempting to achieve higher point densities than original will result in an identical file being created, but I have attempted some fairly modest densities/resolutions without luck.

To ensure that my input tiles weren't overlapping and creating duplicate points, I also tried adjusting the `opt_chunk_size` to both higher and lower values.

In summary:

1. Can homogenize remove streaking at the edges of overlapping points?

**Update:** Homogenizing points didn't help much and I suspect errors in calibration/post-processing

2. Why does R indicate successful homogenization, while the output files remain the same?

**Update**: I solved this problem by simply restarting PC and rerunning code with a different working directory.

[10m interquartile range [IQR] with streaking at edges with point cloud overlaid and colored by point density visualized in Global Mapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9YLu.png)

In R:

```
library(lidR) #lidR version 4.0.4
library(future)
#load normalized LAZ tiles
ctg <- readLAScatalog("path/", filter = "-drop_class 2") #drop ground classes from normalized tiles
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg)<- 200
opt_chunk_size(ctg)<- 0 #maintain chunk size 750m = 2460.63ft

summary(ctg) #input catalog
class       : LAScatalog (v1.1 and 1.2 format 1)
extent      : x1, x2, y1, y2 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NAD83 / New York Central (ftUS) 
area        : 2275.8 kus-ft²
points      : 10.74 billion points
density     : 4.7 points/us-ft²
density     : 2.5 pulses/us-ft²
num. files  : 422 
proc. opt.  : buffer: 200 | chunk: 0
input opt.  : select: * | filter: -drop_class 2
output opt. : on disk | w2w guaranteed | merging enabled

plan(multisession, workers = 3L) 
opt_output_files(ctg)<- paste0("path/retile\_{XLEFT}\_{YBOTTOM}") # select output and naming for tiles 

ctg_thinned = decimate_points(ctg, homogenize(density = 1, res= 10.76, use_pulse = FALSE)) #1 pt/~1m^2 in feet

summary(ctg_thinned) #output catalog
class       : LAScatalog (v1.1 and 1.2 format 1)
extent      : x1, x2, y1, y2 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NAD83 / New York Central (ftUS) 
area        : 2257.83 kus-ft²
points      : 1.69 billion points
density     : 0.7 points/us-ft²
density     : 0.5 pulses/us-ft²
num. files  : 421 
proc. opt.  : buffer: 5 | chunk: 0
input opt.  : select: * | filter: -drop_class 2
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. How did you build the density map? I do not understand the density map you produced. I see densities ranging from 0 to 15 which mean that the decimation failed? Please be more specific on what you did and why you think there is a problem. What is the resolution of the density map? Does global mapper use a buffer to build the density map? What the density map produced by lidR looks like. I need all of these informations to help.

Comment: @JRR In terms of what I did, I normalized/filtered out non-veg/non-grnd points in GM and retiled everything as 750m LAZ files and opened in R. The density map was made in GM by dragging in tiles from output folder assigned using `opt_output_files(ctg)` then selecting "Color by Pt. Density" (based on full pt. cloud loaded). I made `grid_density()` plots of few tiles of the orig. `ctg` and `ctg_thinned`. They are identical and on the same scale (0 to 1.2). However, the thinning at tile edges are now gone in lidR plot (good). `summary()` shows lower points but the point cloud appears identical?

Comment: While possibly seeming tedious, @jrr suggests you put the above comment as code used in your question, rather than in comment, both as your approach thinned edges (the good result) that would have allowed him to see your process, and to help others who will land here later searching for the code used.

Comment: @Kong_746 Sorry I did not understand anything. Please edit your original question, try to organize your ideas, show images, code example and do not assume I know your software. My best guess so far is that GM is wrong and do not buffer the tiles.

Comment: @JRR Appreciate it, and sorry for the confusion. I ended up solving my homogenization problem by simply restarting and rerunning everything. So yes, big deal over nothing.  I think my striping artifacts are here to stay and will need to work with other variables.